# Существует ли способ обновить маршруты у клиента?

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация, openvpn

Имеется сервер openvpn с кучей клиентов на разных платформах (пк win, lin, смартфоны).

Требуется периодически обновлять маршруты у клиентов (т.е. делать push "route x.x.x.x x.x.x.x")

*Существует ли возможность добавить маршрут уже подключенному клиенту, или дропнуть его, чтобы он переподключился и подгрузил новые маршруты через скрипт clent-connect?*

P.S. На данный момент я вижу только вариант остановки сервера, ожидания некоторого времени пока все клиенты закроют сокеты и запуска, с последующим переподключением клиентов.

Answer (score 1):

Windows:
На клиенте [установить Прослушиватель RIP](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd469737(v=ws.11).aspx) - в компонентах Windows есть, но не навсех версиях. Есть старое (2012г) стороннее решение http://www.xorp.org

Linux:
Quagga - поддерживает все основные протоколы обмена маршрутами, включая [rip](/questions/tagged/rip). Ещё [ripng](/questions/tagged/ripng) [ospf](/questions/tagged/ospf), [bgp](/questions/tagged/bgp).

На сервер:
Ту же Quagga.

На Андроид: есть сборки прложений на основе линуксовых. Требуется root.

Comment: Лучше, наверное ospf. Но это не самый простой вариант. К тому же не получится поднять на мобильных клиентах. Или я не прав? Тут скорее интересует возможность обновлять маршруты средствами самого openvpn

Comment: rip поднимается намного проще. На виндах есть родная служба, на многих роутерах есть поддержка rip. Я люблю его для простых сетей - просто включил и заработало. ospf надо настраивать и понимать мультикаст.

Comment: @KirilliusLabutin чот погуглил и нашел ospf на андроид. не проверял, но возможно теоретически.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл способ, как дропнуть клиента.
В конфиге прописывается порт для управления службой через telnet
management localhost 7505
А затем через telnet можно дропать клиента командой kill CLIENT_NAME, после чего клиент переподключается и заново подгружает маршруты.

Comment: норм, только разрыв приложений получается..)